# Trying to run streamlit on python terminal and i keep getting this error

Tags: python, terminal, pycharm, streamlit

for some reason i can no longer run streamlit from my Pycharm terminal, no matter what i do on any project even ones that have worked previously i cant run it, any ideas

this is the errors im getting (go easy on me im a newbie)

[screen shot of erros](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BkXJG.png)

any help much appreciated

Comment: Please share a [mcve] and see [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors)

Answer (score 0):

The issue is raising due to the config.toml file. You need to  delete the config.toml file which can be found in the directory where you have installed streamlit in your local machine.
If you are not able to locate your the directory, then run:

```
streamlit cache clear
```

You will get output similar to this which will tell you where is your .streamlit directory exactly, take this path before the cache part.

```
Output: Nothing to clear at {Username}{path}.streamlit\cache.
```

Run: `cd {Username}\{path}\.streamlit`

You will be able to see config.toml here and just delete that file.

Answer (score 0):

```
  pip install streamlit
```

get the info about streamlit

```
 pip show streamlit
```

this will output

```
Name: streamlit
Version: 1.25.0
Summary: A faster way to build and share data apps
Home-page: https://streamlit.io
Author: Snowflake Inc
Author-email: hello@streamlit.io
License: Apache License 2.0
Location: /home/t/.local/lib/python3.11/site-packages
Requires: altair, blinker, cachetools, click, gitpython, importlib-metadata, numpy, packaging, pandas, pillow, protobuf, pyarrow, pydeck, pympler, python-dateutil, requests, rich, tenacity, toml, tornado, typing-extensions, tzlocal, validators, watchdog
Required-by:
```

the important property is the `location`

```
Location: /home/t/.local/lib/python3.11/site-packages
```

that means `streamlit` installed in pytthon.3.11. so

```
python3.11 -m streamlit run yourfile.py
```